# Compare 2 lists to find an equal or approximate match without doing N^2 iteration

Tags: python, performance, list

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [101, 110, 136]
list2 = [101.04, 264.5, 379.9, 466.4, 629.6, 724.4, 799.8, 914.3]
```

Iterate over `list1` and compare each element in this list with the elements in `list2`. If there is a number encountered in the 2nd list which is an exact match or an approximate match to the element in `list1` then output that match.

Note: I want to avoid the N^2 iteration strictly as I want to do it as efficiently as possible

Comment: Looks like you need some code, however, can you show your attempts?

Comment: And please explain approximate match?

Comment: "Do this task for me" questions tend not to be received well. Can you show what you've tried? Simply rewriting your question in the form of a question instead of what reads like a command would probably improve your chances, too.

Comment: Will the lists be sorted when you get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this problem is slightly tricky. The code below should work for any dataset and margin value, but I haven't extensively tested it.

The only way to avoid O(N^2) performance is to have the data sorted, which allows for two index values to be used, so that you can walk across the second list at a different rate than the first and still have valid comparisons.

The code below will print out every match in List2 for every item in List1, so the printing may have some duplicates, hence the performance will be slightly worse than O(n), but it will be better with smaller margins. (Large margin chosen here to exaggerate the effects of setting it high or low).

```
list1 = [101, 110, 136, 380]
list2 = [101.04, 110.009, 264.5, 379.9, 466.4, 629.6, 724.4, 799.8, 914.3]
#guarantee that lists are sorted
list1.sort()
list2.sort()
#Set margin differently as needed
margin = 100
idx = 0;
for i in list1:
    while i > list2[idx] and not abs(i - list2[idx]) <= margin:
        idx+=1
    tempIdx = idx
    #Print out all the elements in list2 that are within the margin for list1
    while abs(i - list2[tempIdx]) <= margin:
        print list2[tempIdx]
        tempIdx+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about what approximate means?

```
>>> list1 = [101, 110, 136]
>>> list2 = [101.04, 264.5, 379.9, 466.4, 629.6, 724.4, 799.8, 914.3]
>>> set(int(x) for x in list1) & set(int(x) for x in list2)
set([101])
```

Simple, but if `list2` is `[100.96, 264.5, 379.9, ...` you won't get a match

When you define "approximate", you can start thinking properly about a solution.

If the lists are presorted it would be a helpful thing to mention

Comment: Perhaps using the `set.intersection` method would be nicer than `&`?

Comment: @downvoter, This ill specified question appears to be abandoned but you _didn't_ downvote that. Why downvote my answer which is actually correct for some values of "approximate"? Can you do better?

Answer (score 1):

This should give O(nlogn) time (because of two sorts), with a user-specified tolerance, epsilon.  It's loosely based on the merge step of mergesort:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import pprint

def approximate_matches(list1, list2, epsilon = 0.5):
    len_list1 = len(list1)
    len_list2 = len(list2)

    list1_index = 0
    list2_index = 0

    while list1_index < len_list1 and list2_index < len_list2:
        list1_element = list1[list1_index]
        list2_element = list2[list2_index]

        difference = abs(list1_element - list2_element)

        if difference < epsilon:
            yield (list1_element, list2_element)
            list1_index += 1
            list2_index += 1
        elif list1_element < list2_element:
            list1_index += 1
        elif list2_element < list1_element:
            list2_index += 1
        else:
            raise AssertionError('Unexpected else taken')


def main():
    list1 = [101.0, 110.0, 136.0, 379.6, 800.0, 900.0]
    list2 = [101.04, 264.5, 379.9, 466.4, 629.6, 724.4, 799.8, 914.3]

    list1.sort()
    list2.sort()

    pprint.pprint(list(approximate_matches(list1, list2)))

main()
```

HTH

PS: Note that if one number in list1 matches two numbers in list2 (or vice versa), this code will only report one match.